# what is the difference between ./ and / (root and current directory)?

Tags: unix, path, filesystems

whats is the difference between these two?
Let say file a and b sits in the same folder and we want to include b in file a. 
Isn't ./b and /b the same thing? which one should I use?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not a programming question. I suggest deleting it and posting in [unix.se].

Comment: On the other hand, you mentioned wanting to "include" one file in another, which suggests you're asking about using `#include`. If that's the case, then it is a programming question, but as it stands it's extremely unclear. If you're asking about `#include` directives, include some code whose meaning you're trying to understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`./b` and `/b` are the same thing if and only if your current working directory is `/`. You should use the former<sup>(a)</sup>.

By way of further clarification, let's say your current working directory is `/my_code_dir` and you have code of the form:

```
#include "./b.h"
#include "/b.h"
```

Putting aside the whole issue of C inclusions being implementation-defined, the former will use `/my_code_dir/b.h` and the latter will use `/b.h`.

---

<sup>(a)</sup> Assuming they are your only two choices, of course. In any decent-sized development environment, you probably should be avoiding these "breadcrumb"-style paths (like `../../../include/xyzzy/plugh.h`) and instead rely on the your environment setting up include paths for you (so you can just use `xyzzy/plugh.h`). That way, things can move around freely without having to go and change large swathes of code.